# How to add coldfusion server on CFEclipse

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion

I am new to ColdFusion and just inherited a ColdFusion project that I need to debug.

So far I have installed ColdFusion 11, Eclipse (LUNA), and CFEclipse.

From CFEclipse I am able to import my project from a location like `C:\Users\MyName\MyProjectName` and view all the files. However, when I tried to add coldfusion server using the Servers tab, I don't see ColdFusion among the server types. I tried the "Download additional server adapters" link, no luck. 
When I tried to use Browser View tab at the lower panel of the editor to see the index.cfm page, I get a "This program cannot display the webpage" error.

What have I missed? Please help.

Comment: After downloading ColdFusion, did you install it?

Comment: Yes, I did. But when I tried to access admin using http://localhost/cfide/administrator and http://localhost:8500/cfide/administrator, I got HTTP 404 and "This webpage is not available" errors respectively.

Comment: I've not used CFEclipse before, but it sounds like you need to get ColdFusion working on its own first. What web server are you running it on - the internal developer server, or on a local install of Apache or IIS?

Comment: I'm trying to make it work with IIS. I have IIS 7.5 installed and created a virtual folder pointing to my code base. If I type localhost to the browser, I get the IIS 7 logo. If I type localhost/MyVirtualDir/index.cfm, I get the following error: "Service Temporarily Unavailable!
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
 Jakarta/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.40 "

Answer (score 0):

According to the following article, I found and ran cfstart.bat under my /ColdFusion/cfusion/bin folder, and apache is up and running.
http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/02/coldfusion-11-getting-started-server.html

I am still hazy about how the whole thing works, but at least now I can access to the ColdFusion Administrator at http://localhost/CFIDE/administrator/ with password 'admin' like the article suggests, and the 'Browser View' tab in CFEclipse is now working properly.